# How can I parse XML file which ask for credentials in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, python-2.7

> Can someone help here, I want to parse a XML file which asks for authentication(user, password) but with my code. Can someone help what should I use or edit in my code so that my code can parse svn https link?

```
import urllib.request as url
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile=url.urlopen(r'file:///D:/Python/user.html')

def fileparse(xmlfile):
   tree=ET.parse(xmlfile)
   root=tree.getroot()
   #print(root.tag)

   users={root.get("name"):[]}

   for item in root.findall("client"):
      users[root.get("name")].append(item.get("name"))
   return users


k1=input("user or client, please mention:")
if k1=='user':
   k10=input("Enter the user id you want to search for:")
   d1=fileparse(xmlfile)

   for k,v in d1.items():
      if k==k10:
         print(k,v)
elif k1=='client':
   c10=input("Enter the client name you want to search for:")
   d1=fileparse(xmlfile)

   for k,v in d1.items():
      if c10 in v:
         print(k)
else:

   print("sorry please check your input values")
```

Comment: Please update the question with the error and traceback. Aside, Python indentation is four spaces, it appears as though you are using two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is indentation wrong in your code.

users and for loop should be present inside function to execute.

```
import urllib.request as url
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = url.urlopen(r'file:///D:/Python/user.html').read()


def fileparse(xmlfile):
    tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
    root = tree.getroot()
    # print(root.tag)

    users = {root.get("name"): []}

    for item in root.findall("client"):
        users[root.get("name")].append(item.get("name"))
        return users

print(fileparse(xmlfile))
```

Comment: > Yes but my main concern is that my code is not working when i input https xml file link which ask for credentials , i am trying to put svn https link which i want to parse here

Comment: I think we must read from the source. 
xmlfile = url.urlopen(r'file:///D:/Python/user.html').read()